# Не то, что ожидаю получить в результате копирования

Tags: python

```
>>> a = [22, 44, 111]
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> b
[22, 44, 111]
>>> a[2] = 'aaaa'
>>> a
[22, 44, 'aaaa']
>>> b
[22, 44, 111]
```

Почему *b* в результате [22, 44, 111], а не [22, 44, 'aaaa']?
Я так понимаю, что ответ связан с типом копирования (shallow copy), но разобраться не могу

Comment: вы все правильно получаете. метод `.copy` для того и существует, чтобы копия существовала отдельно от оригинала. если это противоположно желаемому, делайте просто b = a.

Comment: схожий (для понимая может быть полезный) вопрос: [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему b в результате [22, 44, 111], а не [22, 44, 'aaaa']?

потому что `a.copy()` создаёт *новый* список и `a[2] = 'aaaa'` заменяет 3-ий элемент в *старом* списке.

```
>>> a is b 
False
```

`a` и `b` это разные объекты.

Если бы оказалось, что `a[2] = ...` изменяет какой-либо другой список в вашем коде, то это значит что **один и тот же** список имеет несколько имён в вашем коде ([один объект, несколько имён -- посмотрите на картинку](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names)). В данном случае "имя" это просто способ обратиться к объекту, такой как `obj.attr[i][key]`.

Чтобы понять, что копия поверхностная (shallow copy), достаточно поместить в список изменяемый объект (числа, строки неизменяемы (immutable) в Питоне. Списки, словари, функции, объекты пользовательских классов по умолчанию и большинство других объектов являются изменяемыми (mutable) в Питоне):

```
>>> a = [lambda: 1]
>>> b = a.copy() # Python 3, use `b = a[:]` for Python 2/3
>>> a[0].__name__
'<lambda>'
>>> b[0].__name__
'<lambda>'
>>> a[0].__name__ = 'f'
>>> b[0].__name__
'f'
```

В данном случае видно, что оба списка содержат один и тот же объект. Изменение аттрибута `__name__` у первого элемента в списке `a` отражается на аттрибуте  `__name__` у элемента в списке  `b`, потому что `a[0] is b[0]` (элементы являются одним и тем же объектом).

```
>>> a.append(1)
>>> len(a)
2
>>> len(b)
1
```

Пример показывает, что `a` и `b` являются разными объектами. Вызов `.append()` метода добавляет новый элемент только к одному списку. `b` список не меняется.

То что первоначальное содержимое у обоих списков одинаковое оправдывает название метода `.copy()` (копия). То что копия содержит изначальные объекты, а не их копии оправдывает использование прилагательного "поверхностная".

Если при создании копии вложенные объекты также копируются рекурсивно, то это называется "глубокая копия" (deep copy):

```
>>> nested_list = [[]]
>>> shallow_copy = nested_list[:] # создаём поверхностную копию
>>> nested_list[0].append(1) # изменяем элемент в исходном списке
>>> shallow_copy # видим что поверхностная копия отражает эти изменения
[[1]] # первые элементы в оригинале и копии ссылаются на один и тот же объект
>>> import copy
>>> deep_copy = copy.deepcopy(nested_list) # создаём глубокую копию
>>> deep_copy
[[1]]
>>> nested_list[0].append(2) # изменяем элемент в исходном списке
>>> deep_copy  # видим что глубокая копия НЕ изменилась
[[1]]
>>> shallow_copy # видим что поверхностная копия отражает изменения
[[1, 2]]
```

`copy.deepcopy()` не всегда работает, например:

```
>>> import copy
>>> c = copy.deepcopy(b)
>>> c[0].__name__
'f'
>>> b[0].__name__ = 'g'
>>> c[0].__name__
'g'
>>> c[0] is b[0]
True
```

В данном случае `copy.deepcopy()` вернул тот же объект (функцию) вместо создания копии. Я не нашёл удовлетворительного ответа почему так происходит, можно почитать обсуждение в [Why deepcopy doesnt create new references to lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802002/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Если имеется в виду модуль стандартной библиотеки `copy` то он и должен работать именно так.

```
import copy
a = [1,2]
b = copy.copy(a)
a[0] = 'x'
print a # ['x', 2]
print b # [1, 2]
```

Но:

```
import copy
a = [[1,2], 3]
b = copy.copy(a)
c = copy.deepcopy(a)
a[0][0] = 'x'
print a # [['x', 2], 3]
print b # [['x', 2], 3]
print c # [[1, 2], 3]
```

Т.е. `copy` создает "поверхностную" копию объекта, если (в данном случае) элемент списка сам является списком ("ссылочным") типом, то копируется сама ссылка, а `deepcopy` копирует "рекурсивно", т.е. применяет метод копирования ко всем "элементам" объекта, в данном случае - списка.
Грубо (конкретно для списка) метод `copy` работает так:

```
def copy(x):
   y = []
   for item in x:
      y.append(item)
   return y
```

а `deepcopy` так:

```
import collections
def deepcopy(x):
   y = []
   if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
      for item in x:
         y.append(deepcopy(item))
   else:
      y.append(x)
   return y
```

В python3 метод `copy` добавлен к стандартным методам списка (в отличие от 2-го питона, метода `deepcopy` у списков нет ни во 2-ом ни в 3-ем), так что в моих примерах все строки типа `b = copy.copy(a)` можно заменить на `b = a.copy()`. Работать все будет точно так же.

П.С. Добавлю тут ссылку от @jfs: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables
для понимания разницы между изменяемыми/неизменяемыми типами и понятием "имя" в Python

Comment: (1) "ссылочный" ничего не говорит -- все объекты в Питоне "ссылочные". Важно изменяемый объект или неизменяемый. Целое число (`1`) это неизменяемый объект в Питоне, а список (`[]`) -- изменяемый. (2) `deepcopy()` у Вас сломана (как минимум нужно рекурсию остановить -- добавить элементарный случай, чтобы хотя бы со вложенными списками работала функция).

Comment: @jfs (1) потому и поставил кавычки, что это не абсолютно корректно. Опять же, с кортежами ([1,2] -> (1,2)) (неизменяемыми ЕМНИП) все будет работать так же. (2) Да, Вы правы конечно, нужно как-то проверить итерируемость `item`.

Comment: (1) это не мелкая придирка. Использование  "ссылочный" для списка в контексте копирования в корне неверно и демонстрирует фундаментальное непонимание какую роль имена, объекты в Питоне имеют. Очевидно, что к кортежам *"все будет работать так же"*  не применимо в данном случае: они неизменяемы и поэтому `copy.copy()` *может вернуть и действительно возвращает* тот же самый объект:  `copy.copy(some_tuple) is some_tuple`. (2) Вы бы попробовали хотя бы Ваш код запустить (хотя бы после моего явного замечания): `deepcopy([1])` -> `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: (1) ИМХО, Вы не совсем правы. Я не помню, формализовано ли понятие "ссылочного" типа в Питоне, но факт, что `copy.copy` и моя версия совершенно одинаково сработают и для `[[1,2], 3]` и для `[(1,2), 3]` (и даже для `[SomeObject(), 3]`. Снаружи должен быть именно список (точнее изменяемый итерируемый объект с корректной реализацией `append`) (2) Я же с Вами согласился уже). Поправил чуть ответ (только для вложенных списков). Подчеркну, что мои примеры - далеко не полный аналог методов `copy.copy copy.deepcopy` - лишь грубые прикидки.

Comment: @jfs, кстати, спасибо за конструктивные замечания.

Comment: про Вашу функцию `copy()` я ничего не говорил (это просто многословный способ сказать `x[:]` для списков). Ещё раз: такие фразы как *"если (в данном случае) элемент списка сам является списком ("ссылочным") типом, то копируется сама ссылка"* только вводят в заблуждение. Я понимаю откуда желание использовать такие слова как "ссылочный тип" берутся: Питон не в первой дюжине языков для меня был и я также сперва усложнённую модель в голове имел. Попробуйте думать в терминах [имён и изменяемых/неизменяемых объектов, чтобы понять как копирование работает](http://goo.gl/sUCevJ)

Comment: @jfs, кажется, я понял, что Вы имеете в виду. Еще раз спасибо. Единственное замечание: в случае `copy` изменяемость/неизменяемость элемента (будь то элемент списка или атрибут объекта) значения не имеет. А (насколько я понимаю) термин "имя" близок к термину "ссылка". С Вашего позволения, вставлю вашу ссылку в ответ.

Comment: Изменяемость имеет значение для отладки и понимания что происходит. Как я уже сказал `copy()` разрешено возвращать сам объект, если он неизменяемый, то есть может быть что `copy(immutable) is immutable`. Для понимания что происходит важно знать работаем ли мы с тем же объектом или с новым объектом, например, это может подсказать будет ли операция `O(1)` или `O(n)`. В специальных случаях `copy.deepcopy()` может вернуть сам объект даже для изменяемых объектов (что может быть неприятным сюрпризом при отладке бага) -- см. [пример с `lambda` в моём ответе.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488018).

Comment: "ссылка" в  разных языках (таких как C++, Java, Rust) может разные вещи означать. Если человек знаком с языком, в котором уже используется понятие ссылка, это может ложные ожидания создать. Понятие ссылка также полезно в Питоне, например, чтобы о garbage collection рассуждать, но в большинстве случаев гораздо проще [модель с именами и объектами использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).